# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found in tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9

When i run my project on my IDE it is worked and response is come in browser with localhost:8080/show
/show is my URL path in controller :

[controller side][image]
[pom.xml file][image]

[URL entered on browser][image]

now i am deployed my project war file on tomcat  then i run tomcat and enter this URL in browser localhost:8080/show then this error occurs.

[image]

i am expecting the same result which is coming from my IDE.

Comment: Please don't post code as images but as images. I suspect you are using Spring boot 3 which requires Tomcat 10.

Comment: Please note, code can be copied and pasted directly into your question or answer. For code blocks, surround the code with three (3) backticks ( ` ) on a new line before the start and after the end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

you should name your war file as "ROOT.war" then you can call it using: *localhost:8080/show*

if your war file name for example "myapp.war", then you can call it using:
localhost:8080/myapp/show